# Where does iPhone simulator put data files?

Tags: iphone, xcode

If I compile my iPhone App with a database that has been built into the bundle what path do I have to use to find the file so that I can open it, as in:

```
FMDatabase* db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:@"/???/database.sqlite"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your  `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

set the following code:

```
databaseName=@"yourfileName.sqlite";    
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    [self checkAndCreateDatabase];
```

-(void) checkAndCreateDatabase
{

```
BOOL success;


NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

if(success) return;
else
    printf("NO File found");

NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

[fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];
```

}

Comment: Thanks will work with that and for the near instantaneous response. What I don't have an understanding of is the relationship between where data files are located on the development machine, the simulator and the working device (iPhone/iPad).

Comment: /Users/username/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/ There you have to go under your sdk the simulator is using like /5.1, then /Applications/projectNumber/Documents/

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this regardless of simulator or device. Please dont forget to add db file to your project folder and add to your bundle.

```
#define DATABASE @"databasefile.sqlite"


NSArray *documentPaths      = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir      = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
databasePath                = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:DATABASE]];
```